# DNS and IP address understanding

Tags: networking, dns, ip-address

I am not pretty much sure on whether my understanding is correct or not regarding DNS and IP address. But here is what I am trying to do

I have started one webserver on my android mobile [ijetty]. There i have created some web application. It is accessible on my mobile.

I took my external ip address from whatismyip.com. Then appended this ip address with port number of the server. I tried it on some other mobile which was using wifi connection tethered from my mobile, I was able to login to the application.

But when I tried the same url on my office computer, it was not working and it said `The request timed out before the page could be retrieved.`

As per my understanding DNS is just a mapping of ip address with domain name and if i make a host file entry of the domain name, i can access that page without providing ip address. So why I am not able to access application hosted on my mobile phone.

Please correct me where I am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of DNS is correct.

The problem you are facing is of a non-static IP. The android device you are using must be getting its IP from somewhere. Most probably the GSM/LTE/CDMA Service Provider or the WiFi it is connected to i.e. from your ISP. The IP obtained thus is not quaranteed to be same all the time and new/available IP will be leased to you on subsequent lease renewal. Try taking a look at whatismyip from your android device (Server) again and see if the IP is same as you used previously.

Comment: Thanks for your response, just one small doubt, as long as the ip address remains constant (till i haven't turned my screen off), I should be able to access the application, don't you think so. but I am unable to access it.

Comment: The error means that you can hit the IP but the request is timing out. Can you look at logs on your ijetty? Look at this to configure logging. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging

Comment: hi, It might be silly, I have just started learning jetty, So not very much sure how to get the logs. But I tried with ES file explorer remote access using `ftp://myexternalip:port/` but still I was not able to access my SD card, same response I am getting on browser.